# How to run height 100% on Safari(version 10.1.2)

Tags: html, css, safari, bulma

I come to you to try to solve a problem that I often encounter on Safari (version 10.1.2). And every time I have to change my method completely to avoid this problem. But today I would like to find a solution.

I use **Bulma** for the css and I have a **100% height that doesn't work on Safari**. I know that one of the solutions is to give a divalent parent a fixed height, but in this case I don't want for the responsiv. Do you have another solution for each image to be the same size?
**You can open the jsfiddle on chrome to see the result I would like to have and open it in Safari to understand the problem** (Of course you need to have the right version of safari, if you have the last one you won't have this problem).

html:

```
<div class="columns is-mobile">
  <div class="column is-3-desktop is-3-tablet is-4-mobile">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://www.myfrenchstartup.com/logo/51306482cdb15_yummypets2.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

   <div class="column is-3-desktop is-3-tablet is-4-mobile">
     <div class="content">
      <img src="https://www.spot-a-shop.fr/images/shops/sportsaventure.png" alt="">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
body {
  background-color: grey;
}


.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items:center;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/12ba8yej/21/

this is what it looks like on safari:
[image]

and here's what I want:
[image]

> 100% height is not taken into account!!!

Comment: I see no difference

Comment: I'm stupid, I confused safari with firefox. I meant safari... I'll change the title and text right now.

Answer (score 0):

**Is this you want ??**

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items:center;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns is-mobile">
    <div class="column is-3-desktop is-3-tablet is-4-mobile">
        <div class="content"> <img src="https://www.myfrenchstartup.com/logo/51306482cdb15_yummypets2.jpg" alt=""> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column is-3-desktop is-3-tablet is-4-mobile">
        <div class="content"> <img src="https://www.spot-a-shop.fr/images/shops/sportsaventure.png" alt=""> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I want, I just want the first image to face the same size as the other one. 100vh the problem is that they're going to take the whole page. I will display the result I would like to see

Comment: @mathiasF , `I will display the result I would like to see ` , mean ??

Comment: In my question above I show what I would like to have as a result